# Run script/automator action from bluetooth event

Tags: automator, bluetooth, siri

I've just started using a new pair of wireless headphones, that have some assistant magic integrated. That works great on my phone, but on my Mac it does nothing (or, it tries to do something to Siri, but she's not really around)

I'd like to somehow map that action to something else - preferably something I can customize to my needs.

From the Console app, I can see that at least 2 bluetooth events happen when I do this - `handsFree:siriStatus` and `handsFree:activateSiri`, both under the `bluetoothaudiod` process. Is it possible somehow to react to these bluetooth events, or are their actions hardcoded in the OS?

Comment: Have a look at the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274043/how-to-check-if-a-bluetooth-keyboard-is-connected-in-macos#comment117190882_66274043) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274043/how-to-check-if-a-bluetooth-keyboard-is-connected-in-macos#comment117190882_66274043. Even though it's asking about a Bluetooth keyboard, nonetheless the comments under the answer still apply just substituting the device type. Another option is using a third-party app e.g. [EventsScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/Event_Parameters.html#table1-l)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll try looking at some of those comments and see if they're helpful!

Comment: If you have any questions about my first comment in the linked question or about EventScripts, just let me know. I am not affiliated with the developer of EventScripts, just a satisfied user.

Comment: I'm not sure EventsScripts will do what I need - I don't care about connect/disconnect events, but specific actions triggered over bluetooth. But your comment and others have led me towards the apple dev docs and I think there might be an answer there

Comment: I've spent quite some time now, and I've found the docs that seem relevant, but I can't figure out how to actually react to these events. There's a `processATCommand` function that I can see is called from the Console logs, but I've no idea how to interact with it from user space.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent application that can harness these events to perform actions.

- https://c-command.com/blog/2022/10/12/toothfairy-2-8-2/

You can try it for free with setapp or subscribe to it or pay for it directly. For sure kick the tires in case it’s not powerful enough for your specific action desired.